# how to destroy session and cookies from same server in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, session-cookies

I have drupal login module which will trigger whenever user login from wordpress site it will be triggered and login to the site but when user logout from drupal it doesnt logout from wordpress. Please check with the below code and guide me solve this problem

```
function wp_login_user_logout( $account) {          
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']); 
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/','sitedomain.com');
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant modify cookies of another domain from one domain.

so I suggest you create some kind of api like this.

on WordPress installation...

```
<?php

// file: wp/api/logout.php
require_once("../wp-load.php");


if(empty($_GET["email"])) {
    die('no email given');
}

// get wordpress user_id by email
$email = $_GET["email"];
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
$user_id =  $user->ID;


// get all sessions for user with ID $user_id
$sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user_id);

// we have got the sessions, destroy them all!
$sessions->destroy_all();

print("user logged out.");
```

now if you access url of your wordpress like this(be sure to url encode email id):
https://example.com/api/logout.php?email=email%40gmail.com

it will logout user with email id: email@gmail.com

now you can do curl request from your drupal to this url.

off course **this is not very secure (one can logout any user if they have email id)**

Comment: yes i am using same server for the both sites. wordpress will be inside the folder on the site root directory

Comment: the user id is different from wordpress and drupal

Comment: Getting http 500 error when i logout bcoz of require once included path

Comment: user id is different from wordpress and drupal it will not have same user id

Comment: answer updated with api code you can use. make sure you update code to use some security mechanism...

Comment: Is there any way to call the theme function.php instead of writing api